# Laravel - How to add If in Request?

Tags: laravel, if-statement

i have a section in my website with a search google maps api.

now i have this: when i enter to domain.com/fields?address_latitude=-34.5396425&address_longitude=-58.705582&dif=1
it show all places arround in 1km... It work perfect.

```
public function index(Request $request) {

        if ($request)
        {
            $query=trim($request->get('address_latitude'));
            $query2=trim($request->get('address_longitude'));
            $query3=trim($request->get('dif'));

            $latitude       =       $query;
            $longitude      =       $query2;
            $dif = $query3;
    
            $shops          =       DB::table("shops");
    
            $shops          =       $shops->select("*", DB::raw("6371 * acos(cos(radians(" . $latitude . "))
                                * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(" . $longitude . "))
                                + sin(radians(" .$latitude. ")) * sin(radians(latitude))) AS distance"));
            $shops          =       $shops->having('distance', '<', $dif);
            $shops          =       $shops->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
    
            $shops          =       $shops->get();

            return view('land.fields',["shops"=>$shops,"address_latitude"=>$query,"address_longitude"=>$query2,"dif"=>$query3]);
        }

    }
```

but i need apply a IF in case of i enter in domain.com/fields
i need here display all my places... i have the code of this... but i have problem to make the "IF"

Any can help me please?

Comment: couldn't get you well, can you put your tries to add the condition you are talking about?

Comment: i try adding  if ($request)
        {}else{return view('test');}

if(!empty($request){ xxxxx }else {return view('test');}

Comment: you may try to check request array not request object: it should be like the following if(count($request->all()){}else{return view('test');}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `when()`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

You can add a condition, where if it's truthy / available, it will add to the query

From the example:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
            return $query->where('role_id', $role);
        })
        ->get();
```

Here, it will only do the `$query->where('role_id', $role);` if the `$role` is true / has a value

Comment: hello, thanks you, but i need make IF for all function and one else to display a simple view...

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but I think you are looking for this `$request->has()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present . With this you can check if the request has a certain value present, it can also accept an array of values